# Vanishing multivariable polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, polynomials

> Let $ \mathbb{K} $ be a field and consider $ f \in \mathbb{K}[x_{1}, \dots ,x_{n}] $ such that the maximum degree of $ f $ in each of the $ x_{i}$'s  is $ d_{i} \in \mathbb{N} $. Let $ S_{1}, \dots , S_{n} \subset \mathbb{K} $ such that $ |S_{i}|> d_{i} $ for all $ i $ from $ 1 $ to $ m $. Show that if $ f $ vanishes on all the points of $ S_{1}\times \cdots \times S_{n} $, then $ f $ vanishes on all of $ \mathbb{K}^{n} $.

I was thinking of using the one variable result for polynomials over integral domains saying that such a polynomial $ f $ has at most $ \deg(f) $ roots, but I don't know how can I apply it here.

I would appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: $S_1,\ldots,S_n$ should be numbers.

Comment: This screams for induction, doesn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof is very easy:

Assuming the result for $n-1$ you get for all $a \in S_1$, that $f(a,x_2, \dotsc, x_n) \in K[x_2, \dotsc, x_n]$ is the zero-polynomial, because it vanishes on $S_2 \times \dotsc \times S_n$.

Hence the univariate polynomial $f(X,x_2, \dotsc, x_n) \in K(x_2, \dotsc, x_n)[X]$ has $|S_1| > d_1$ roots, which shows $f=0$ by the well known base case $n=1$.